# FileSaver.js with a Fabric canvas

Tags: canvas, meteor, fabricjs, filesaver.js

I was trying to use FileSaver.js with a Fabric.canvas object, but it seems that Fabric js has no blob option.

I'm using the Meteor framework by the way.

How can I export a Fabric canvas without using the basic canvas.toDataUrl ?'

Thanks :)

Comment: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js, the github of FileServer

Comment: you can easily convert your dataURI string to a blob http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata/5100158#5100158

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve this by using the native Canvas element.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");

// ... your code here ...

canvas.getElement().toBlob(function(blob) {
  saveAs(blob, "canvas.png");
});
```

And if you want this to work with Safari, you can use the Sebastian Tschan [Javascript Canvas to Blob polyfill](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob).

Answer (score 1):

Fabric has no direct option of Blob. But you can export it in json by `canvas.toJSON()` or in image by `canvas.toDataURL()`. Then you convert the data in blob simply doing this.

**Export** fabric canvas in **blob**:

```
  var data = JSON.stringify(canvas.toJSON()),           
        blob = new Blob([data], {type: "octet/stream"});
```

or

```
  var data = canvas.toDataURL(),           
        blob = new Blob([data], {type: "octet/stream"});
```

[See in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mahbub_rahman/m04c3smj/6/)

Comment: Thanks, that's a pretty good idea. The problem is that it doesn't work with Safari...

Comment: For me, the png gets outputted as base64 data. So it's an invalid image file. Upon debugging, I notice that variable blob2's data property has the same base64 data set to it  as variable data2. Isn't the blob function supposed to turn this base64 into binary data?